# python script to increment value of naive spreadsheet macro

Tags: python, excel, macros

I have a simple macro function in a spreadsheet, looks like this:

```
=LOOKUP(B2, eligible.submissions!A1:A158,eligible.submissions!B1:B158)
```

I want to increment it as so:

```
=LOOKUP(B2, eligible.submissions!A1:A158,eligible.submissions!B1:B158)
=LOOKUP(B3, eligible.submissions!A1:A158,eligible.submissions!B1:B158)
=LOOKUP(B4, eligible.submissions!A1:A158,eligible.submissions!B1:B158)
```

but the click and drag feature increments every single thing- and that is wrong.

Is it possible the use Python to increment only that first value of the function, the one associated with B, i.e. `B2`, `B3`, `B4`, ... etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see what does this have anything to do with Python, but try putting a `$` sign in front of references that you don't want to change, ie:

```
=LOOKUP($B2, eligible.submissions!$A$1:$A$158,eligible.submissions!$B$1:$B$158)
```

See [Overview of Excel formulas](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Overview-of-formulas-d258ec72-149a-42ac-8eae-b50a667eb491) for details:

> **Absolute references** An absolute cell reference in a formula, such as $A$1, always refer to a cell in a specific location. If the position of the cell that contains the formula changes, the absolute reference remains the same. If you copy or fill the formula across rows or down columns, the absolute reference does not adjust. By default, new formulas use relative references, and you may need to switch them to absolute references. For example, if you copy or fill an absolute reference in cell B2 to cell B3, it stays the same in both cells =$A$1.